# Linux commands for login to Github CLI in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, github-actions, workflow, github-cli

I want to login into the gh cli with parameters or flags. Im setting up a cloud-init file, with bash commands. So i can't interact manual processes:
That's how it would look like if you do it manually in the console:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-112:~/react$ gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? HTTPS
? Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials? Yes
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Paste an authentication token
Tip: you can generate a Personal Access Token here https://github.com/settings/tokens
The minimum required scopes are 'repo', 'read:org', 'workflow'.
? Paste your authentication token: ****************************************
- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol https
✓ Configured git protocol
✓ Logged in as yuuval
```

I tried it with this line of code which is printed:

```
- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol https
```

But it doesnt really log you into github cli. This is my Cloud-init file:

```
#cloud-config
keyboard:
    layout: ch
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
    - nginx
    - git
package_reboot_if_required: true
runcmd:
  - type -p curl >/dev/null || sudo apt install curl -y
    curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
    && sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install gh -y
  - mkdir react
  - cd react
  - curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.300.1/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
  - tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
  - yes "" | ./config.sh --url https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws --token AVYXWHVAXX2TB4J63XBJCIDDYB6TA
  - sudo ./svc.sh install
  - sudo ./svc.sh start
  - //HERE COMES THE LOGIN PART + GH WORKFLOW RUN NODE.JS.YML FILE
  - cd _work
  - cd react-deploy-aws
  - cd react-deploy-aws
  - cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
  - sudo rm default
  - 
    echo "server {listen 80 default_server;server_name _;location / {root
    /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/react-deploy-aws/build;try_files
    \$uri /index.html;}}" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  - sudo service nginx restart
  - sudo chmod +x /home
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/react-deploy-aws
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/build
```

Does anyone know how to login via commandline and no user inputs. And if you know how to do the same with the gh workflow run command and then selecting the node.js.yaml file without user interactions needed that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an environment variable with your generated [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) e.g. `PAT`.

Pass it to `gh auth login` command with `--with-token` flag:

```bash
gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token <<< $PAT
```

Reference:

- https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

Comment: Could i do the following aswell:
gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token <<< tokenvalue without the environment variable set

Comment: @CrvxSG: You want to hardcode your token?

Comment: yep, or should i create an file and save the token there?

Comment: @CrvxSG: I wouldn't recommend hardcoding it. Yes, you can save it as a file but adding it to your repo would expose it to everyone who has access to it. Also, for any token change/update, you'll have to push a commit to your repo in both cases. In the case of an env var, you'll just have to configure it and the rest of the workflow would be the same.

Comment: im new to programming so im a little confused. Where can i set the environment variable in github?

Comment: @CrvxSG: By env var, I mean to have it as a secret. In GitHub, secrets can be configured for organizations, repos, and actions. And, they are not visible as cleartext. I'm assuming you already have something similar for your setup e.g. with `aws/secretsmanager`.

Comment: I have a repository secret variable. but this is only for the repository... The Personal Token i already created

Comment: @CrvxSG: Right. Yes, you can utilize that and create it as a repo secret. That should work.

Comment: @CrvxSG: Check this tutorial: https://docker.awsworkshop.io/41_codepipeline/10_setup_secretsmanager_github.html

Comment: The problem is i need to do this all with code and no user interaction. Thats a critea for my school project... So its not enough if i set the PAT variable with the value and login to github with this gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token <<< $PAT

Comment: @CrvxSG: Well, storing it as a secret doesn't need any user interaction. It could be handled with commands. But, if it's just a school project, and you are comfortable hardcoding your PAT, then it should simply store it in a file e.g. `gh.token` and use it as `gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token < gh.token`.

Comment: I created now an environment variable under the repository settings => Environments add (named PAT) => Env variables and created there the variable (PAT with an value)

Comment: @CrvxSG: Good. Now, you can try and use that.

Comment: Now it says: First copy your one-time code: code;



                                                         Open this URL to continue in your webbrowser: {url to github}/login/device; I entered this command: gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token <<< $PAT @Azeem

Comment: Can i do this without any interaction also no interaction to do in github?

Comment: But it worked hardcoded, so thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @CrvxSG: You're welcome! I think those gaps of understanding about env vars, secrets, etc. would be filled with time and experience in the future. All the best to you! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to do this with the workflow file, how to trigger this? (gh run workflow) @Azeem

Comment: @CrvxSG: I'm not sure about that. Please create another question with only that part including all the details and add relevant tags. Hopefully, you'll get the answer.